# I want to display the sku in the product pages of my EDD website

Tags: functions, shortcode

In the functions.php I use:

```
add_shortcode( 'output_post_sku', 'get_sku' );
```

And retrieve it with shortcode: `[output_post_sku]`

It doesn't work. Anyone familiar with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the code for `get_sku`? Is the SKU coming from EDD or somewhere else? When you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific? PHP fatal error? White screen of death? Empty output? Incorrect output?

Answer (score 0):

SKU display on product detail page. Add this code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_sku', 5 );
function show_sku(){
    global $product;
    echo 'SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();
}
```

[image]